# NO INDEX, NO FOLLOW on Specific Category Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, layout, seo

Can I **set a specific category to NO INDEX, NO FOLLOW** in Magento 2? In the previous version I could use an updated layout XML reference to do this within a specific category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by updating category `Layout Update XML` in admin.

**Admin - > Products -> Categories -> Select the category -> Design ->  Layout Update XML -> Add the below code -> Save**

```
<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
</head>
```

Remove cache and check. You can see the changes in front end product category page source.

Comment: This option is no longer present in Magento 2.4.2 so what is the possible solution

Comment: did you find any solution? @CodeForGood

Comment: @MageExplorer, Yes, I solved it with a custom module.

Comment: can you share some info?